# How do I find the best index for the select query

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, mariadb

How do I find the best index for the following query

```
select msgType
     , max(loggedDate)
     , interfaceName
  from LOG_Hl7
 where direction = 'INCOMING'
 group 
    by msgType 
HAVING msgType IN ('ADT');`
```

When I did a explain [image]

Comment: Your query is malformed.  What value do you want for `interfaceName`?  You are not aggregating by it and you have no aggregation function around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, write the query as:

```
select msgType, max(loggedDate), interfaceName
from LOG_Hl7
where direction = 'INCOMING' and msgType = 'ADT'
group by msgType;
```

That is, filter *before* the aggregation, not after.

Then the best index is on `LOG_H17(direction, msgType, loggedDate)`.

`interfaceName` is just hanging out in the `SELECT` clause.  MySQL allows it, but you will be getting an arbitrary value from any row that matches the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I corrected the query and I needed the interfaceName for my business purpose in the application ( interface name is something that is like ADT or RDE which is likely to repeat).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the title, see my [*Indexing Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .

To address your specific query, rewrite the query as Gordon suggests and use his suggested index.  Also address the dangling `interfaceName`.

Hmmm... Your case is missing from my Cookbook.  Build the index from

1. `=` parts of `WHERE`:  `direction` and `msgType`, in either order
2. Add on columns from `GROUP BY`, as the Cookbook says.  But `msgType` is already there.  But it needs to be last (so far) -- this note is missing from the Cookbook.